# Issue With Spacing/Tabbing

Tags: spacing, indentation

I would like to indent in the "of Embryonic Stem Cells" section, but so far everything I have tried has failed.

I first tried to see if there was a tab character, which there does not appear to be, and then I moved on to basically everything I could think of including: making that one line into a stand alone paragraph (`\paragraph{}`), beginning a tabular format (`\begin{tabular}`), attempting to make the white space into an "equation" in a math environment (`\(     \)`), and I even resorted to inserting in spaces by hand - which was unsuccessful in all attempts `(   of...)`, `( \ \ \ \ of...)`, `(\; \; of...)`.

I feel like this has become unnecessarily complicated and I just must be missing something. I've attached the relevant section of my code and the associated PDF output; the highlighted section is where I would like the space to be placed. I'm running the most current version of TeXworks and have no modules installs.

[image: Issue With Code]

Comment: What are you trying to write? A `CV`? There are dedicated `class`es for that. For example `moderncv`. You better use them.

Comment: BTW, Welcome to the site.

Comment: I'll make sure to check them out, since I am writing a CV. A belated thanks for the welcome! This community is wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
\hspace{10pt}
```

where you want to insert a horizontal space.

You can replace "10" with your desired value.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ordinarily, horizontal space at the start of a new line is discarded. You would need `\\ \hspace*{10pt}` in the questioner's example.  Or one can start the new line with something other than a space: `\\ \mbox{}\hspace{10pt}`.

Comment: \hspace*{14mm} worked perfectly for me. After trying so many things it was exciting to finally get it working.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Thanks for choosing this as the best answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\hangindent` command at the start of that paragraph. For example:

```
\hangindent=2em Thesis: \textit{Identification of Differential Genes Associated with Neurogenesis of Embryonic Stem Cells}
```

A few comments on your attempts:

- The `\paragraph` command defines a section heading that is not automatically numbered. The `\par` command splits paragraphs; it is equivalent to a blank line.
- A `tabular` might be a good way to typeset your whole CV (I'm assuming it's a CV), but won't necessarily work for just one line.
- In maths environments, all spaces you enter are ignored; LaTeX does its own spacing.
- Manual spaces seem to have been put at the start of the previous line. LaTeX has it's own complicated way of breaking lines (it tries *every* possible combination!), so you have to play by its rules.

You also use a lot of manual spaces to right-align the year range; you can achieve this with a simple `\hfill` ('horizontal fill space').

Comment: \hangindent was pretty close to working, but I wanted it moved farther over and couldn't seem to get it to do what I wanted. In the end I used hspace*{} to solve my issue. You're right about LaTeX having it's own rule system for line breaks, and my previous attempts with hspace{} failed because I didn't tell it I wanted to override its system.

Thank you for all your assistance and comments. I am writing a CV and am new to LaTeX as a language. What's the benefit of using tabular over sections? Also thanks for the \hfill tip! That made my code much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

another way of getting the indentation would be to use the description environment:

```
\begin{description}
   \item[Thesis:] \emph{Identification of Differential Genes Associated with Neurogenesis of Embryonic Stem Cells}
\end{description}
```

with this solution you would not need to decide where to put your horizontal space, and it will if if the text is changed.

Comment: This worked, but sadly created an entirely new section and thus left white space before and after. But in the end \hspace*{} was what worked for me. Thanks for the help!